# Reducing font size of x value ticks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
xvals   = ['Public Protection', 'Public Works', 'Human Welfare', 'Community Health', 'Culture & Recreation', 'General Administration', 'General City Responsibilities']
x_start = [df.iloc[0, 0], df.iloc[1, 0], df.iloc[2, 0], df.iloc[3, 0], df.iloc[4, 0], df.iloc[5, 0], df.iloc[6, 0]]
y       = [df.iloc[0, 2],  df.iloc[1, 2],  df.iloc[2, 2], df.iloc[3, 2],  df.iloc[4, 2],  df.iloc[5, 2], df.iloc[6, 2]]
matplotlib.pyplot.bar(x = xvals, height = y, width=0.5, bottom=x_start, align='center')
```

I have a bar graph which displays text (xvals) as the x value at the bottom
When I print out the graph, it overlaps each other, I was wondering if there is any way to reduce the size of the text or increase the graph size so the labels won't overlap?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, can you share a sample of your data in order to reproduce it easily. Edit the question and share the `df` content (in text format)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font size for either x or y ticks using the line below and customizing the fontsize parameter and specifying the axis of interest.

```
matplotlib.pyplot.tick_params(axis='x',labelsize=fontsize)
```